# How to get the part inside an "[" and "]" of a string (strange behaviour)

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am trying to get the part of a string between `[` and `]`. So far I have this:

```
For Each a As String In CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), 
    RichTextBox).Text.Split(System.Environment.NewLine())
    If (a.Contains("print ")) Then
        Dim sData As String
        sData = a.Substring(6)
        Dim i, j As Integer
        i = sData.IndexOf("[") + "[".Length
        j = sData.IndexOf("]") - i
        Dim sData1 As String
        sData1 = sData.Substring(i, j)
        Console.WriteLine(sData1)
    End If
Next
```

However, if I have this:

```
print [Hello world!]
print [What's up world?]
```

then the output is this:

```
Hello world!
```

but the required output is:

```
Hello world!
What's up world
```

I.e. it will not display anything after the first time a `print` is found.

So why is that happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: what about this line: `x [print]` You should include a check for that.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Just a quick question, why would I do that? I don't seem to understand.

Comment: The code as written checks for `a.Contains("print")`. That will match the test string I provided. You probably want something more narrowly targeted.

Comment: That's something interesting. Thanks for mentioning it. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) which results in you not being told that `Split(System.Environment.NewLine())` is truncating the CRLF to CR. The lines of a RichTextBox are separated with LF.

The easy solution would be to use the [`.Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the RTB:

```
For Each a As String In CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), RichTextBox).Lines
```

Comment: I am actually using Option Strict On, in a module called Module1.vb - [here's a paste of it](https://pastebin.com/1T6mDP4z). I am gonna try the other part of the answer just now.

Comment: OMG! This is finally working! Thank you so damn much!

Comment: @DDev Unless you set Option Strict On for the whole project then it only applies in the file that it is written in, if that is the case for this code. You should have got an error that "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Char'."

Answer (score 0):

U can go with regex but here's a non-regex solution

```
'U can also use a loop(This is a working solution)

    Dim mystring = "print [Hello world]" + Environment.NewLine + "Print [What's up world?]" + ........
    For Each line In mystring.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Dim hloWorld = line.Split("[")(1)
        Dim result = hloWorld.Replace("]", "")
        Dim finalResult = result + Environment.NewLine
        '''Do what u wanna do with ur final result
    Next
```

Comment: Trying it out RN.

Comment: Does not seem to work. My input is the exact same as the question and the output is:
`Hello world!`
`print`

Comment: a new `this` is a new line in the output btw

Comment: I dont understand... The result is `Hello World` , isn't that what u want ?

Comment: Nope. The result should be `Hello world` on the first line and `What's up world?` on the second. I am getting `Hello world` on the first line and `print` on the second one.

Comment: Does the string look like : `print [Hellow worlds] [What's up world]` ? If no, what is the exact string ?

Comment: u want separate lines in the result ?

Comment: Yup, I need separate lines.

Comment: Re-check the answer :)

Comment: This won't work in the case. I am letting the use do as many `print [something there]`'s as they want. This will let 2.

Comment: U didn't mention that :( ... And u can use a loop if u want and then my code will work :)

Comment: @zackraiyan To properly emulate the text from a RichTextBox, you should have `Dim mystring = "print [Hello world]" & VbLf & "print [What's up world?]"`.

Comment: @zackraiyan The lines of a RichTextBox are separated with LF (Chr(10)), not CRLF (Chr(13) & Chr(10)).